# How do I get the content of sent/received packets and bytes (to/from the internet) of an active local process of a program?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to see, which content I receive and send to the internet from an active, local running application.

Does anyone have a solution to do this in C# (Forms or WPF)?

Comment: Do you mean something like Fiddler? http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Yes but I need it for local applications and not for websites

Comment: If you're communicating on the Internet, Fiddler should do what you want.  If you're not doing HTTP, then something like WireShark might be more suited to what you're doing. http://www.wireshark.org/